Referencing class in function decorator call
I'm trying to pass a parameter to a decorator that references it's own class:
export class SomeClass {
  public async handleError(error: Error): Promise<void> {
    // ... treating errors
  }

  @treat(SomeClass.prototype.handleError) // <- error here
  public async doSomething(): Promise<void> {
    // ... doing something
  }
}

But I'm getting this error:
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SomeClass' before initialization
Is there anyway to do that or will I have to send the name of the treating function and find it inside the decorator?

The decorator expression is evaluated before the class is defined, so yes this cannot work. You can wrap it in an arrow function (that you call from the decorator only after the class variable has been initialised), or you can pass the name as you already suggested.
